# Get form id in formGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-formly

I use ngx formly for building forms. What i need is to access form id inside some of the custom types i have. Basically i need to access form id in formGroup.

**HTML**

```
   <div>
        <form [formGroup]="form" [id]="formId">
            <formly-form [form]="form" [model]="model" [fields]="fields" [options]="options"></formly-form>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**.ts**

```
 formId = "unique_id_from_backend"
 form = new FormGroup({});
```

**Input type component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'input-field',
    templateUrl: './input.html',
})
export class InputFieldComponent extends FieldType implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log(this.form);
        // here i can access formGroup that i am passing in <form> but it seems id property is 
        // not there. Is there some way i can access form id?
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a custom field type, you can access to the field and options instance where you can get the id, key...

For your use case, you may rely on `formState`, so assign the `formId` to `options.formState`:

```
  form = new FormGroup({});
  options = { formState: { id: "unique_id_from_backend" } }
```

```
export class InputFieldComponent extends FieldType implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.formState.id);
  }
}
```